# WebStorm when I transform a var in object all my imports are formatted

Tags: webstorm

Since the last upgrade with WebStorm I have this strange bug.

Some one have this bug and find to fix it ?

[image]

Comment: what did you do namely (how did you transform a var)? I'd say that the resultant formatting doesn't look like a result of code reformatting, Webstorm never formats imports in this way (inserting blank lines between them)

Comment: I just select the var and click on "{"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the issue.

Don't know why but check the `On 'Reformat code' action` on the prettier settings generate this issue.

I have nothing in my `.prettierrc` to do something like that. Probably a webstorm issue.